# Swift: many built-in functions return Optional types. How can I turn them into regular variables without ugly nested ifs?

Tags: ios, swift, nested, option-type

**TL;DR? Please give me an example of how to handle a String init method that might return a String and might return nil, without: 1) assigning it to an optional String var, 2) using ugly nested loops to handle nil/non-nil cases, or 3) assuming it will never be nil with `!`, when it very well could be nil and that would kill my app.**

I'm learning Swift, and trying to send out a REST request. This is the code I wrote to start with:

```
    let restCallStr = String(format:"%@connect/token", arguments:[BASE_REST_URL]);
    restCallStr = restCallStr.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet());
    let restURL = NSURL(string:restCallStr);
    var restRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:restURL);
    restRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
    restRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    let completionClosure: (response:NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> () = {
        var jsonDict:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil) as NSDictionary;
        println("Response: \(jsonDict)");
    };
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(restRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:completionClosure);
```

Looks similar enough to what I'd do in Objective-C, and reads like it ought to work...

But it doesn't. All of the built-in `init` methods I'm calling (`String(format:"", arguments:[])`, `NSURL(string:"")`, etc.) don't return regular String or NSURL variables... They return Optionals.

Now I've done research on optionals, and I believe I understand the basics of how they work. What I'm struggling with is how to handle them practically (and without a ton of ugly excess code everywhere).

Advice on the 'net seems to be "just use `!` to cast it out of the optional" (with naysayers arguing "Noooooo, you should (almost) never use `!`!", and common sense telling me that `!` doesn't make sense here, because if the value is nil I need to handle that, not just crash).

The only solution that seemed to actually handle both the nil and non-nil cases seemed to be `if let`, so I decided to give that a try. Having modified only 2 lines of my original code, I've already begun an ugly tree of nested if statements:

```
    let restURLStr = String(format:"%@connect/token", arguments:[BASE_REST_URL]);
    if let encodedRestURLStr = restURLStr.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    {
        if let restURL = NSURL(string:encodedRestURLStr)
        {
            var restRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:restURL);
            restRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
            restRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST";
            let completionClosure: (response:NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> () = {
                var jsonDict:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil) as NSDictionary;
                println("Response: \(jsonDict)");
            };
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(restRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:completionClosure);
        }
        else
        {
            println("Oops, nil assigned to restURL! Better handle that.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        println("Oops, nil assigned to restCallStr! Better handle that.");
    }
```

And I'm getting a headache already just imagining what it's going to look like (and how many wasted keystrokes will result) if I have to do this *every single time* I make an assignment that could be nil.

There **has** to be a better way. Swift does a lot of nifty things, but right now I'm longing for a chunk of good ol' obj-c code where I don't need a zillion nested statements to handle perfectly acceptable nil values.

What's the way around this, folks? Everyone talks about how Swift is so streamlined and awesome, there's no way this is how this kind of thing is supposed to be handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So they added a new way to unwrap things safely with guard let. You can use myUrl in this example outside so no more nesting with if lets. For example:

```
   guard let myUrl = NSURL(string:"www.myWebsite.com") else {
   return
   }
```